# SPA How to remove the # in the URL when visiting new page?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm using Django and vanilla JavaScript, on my localhost when I click on a button to display a New page my URL turns to localhost:8000/#

How to not show the #?

I'm trying to add a URL to the pages using history.pushState(null, ' ', "all_posts"); for example and now my URL shows

http://localhost:8000/all_posts#

Answer (score 0):

```js
const url = new URL('http://localhost:8000/all_posts#')
url.hash = '';
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the unnecessary characters from `window.location.href` using regex once the page has loaded and then update the URL.

```
let presentURL = window.location.href;

if  ( presentURL.endsWith('#') ) {
  presentURL.replace(/#(\S)/g, '$1');
  window.location.href = presentURL;
} // IF
```

Comment: When I check the URL in the console of JavaScript debugging, it doesn't show the # but on the client-side URL on the browser it shows it

Comment: Could you also check for the `window.location.href` during the `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` event? mentioned here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event